# golangで2chのIDを生成したい

Tags: php, go

https://code.jp.ai/question/155

上記のサイトを参考にしてIDを生成したいと考えているのですが、Goではどのように実装すれば良いのでしょうか。

考えてみましたが、`md5.Sum(ip)`は`[16]byte`型なので`[:30]`のようにスライスできません。
golangにもPHPの`substr`のような関数があれば良いのですが、見つかりませんでした。

どのように実装できるかご教授ください。

Comment: リンク先のコードで使われている PHP の `base64_encode()` と golang の `base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString()` のエンコーディングアルゴリズムは異なるのですが、それは別に構いませんか？

Comment: 今回の利用目的上は問題ないと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- md5ハッシュは16バイト長であると規格で定められています（ただし1バイトを8ビットとします）。

  - PHPの`md5()`はそれを16進表記に直し、32文字にしています([参考](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.md5.php))。
  - Goの`md5.Sum()`は[]byte型のまま結果が得られます([参考](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#Sum))。
- Goで[]byte型を16進数の文字列に変換したい場合、`fmt.Sprintf`が使えると思います。`%x`や`%X`フォーマットが使えます。

  - あるいは、`hex.EncodeToString` でも良さそうです([参考](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#EncodeToString))。ただしarrayとsliceの違いにご注意ください([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886616/convert-array-to-slice-in-go))。
- 部分文字列は、Unicodeのことを考えると簡単には実装できないことが分かります。そのためGoでは、string型、[]byte型、[]rune型を上手く使い分けています。詳しくは 

  ["Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go - The Go Blog"](https://blog.golang.org/strings) を見て下さい。

  - 入力される文字列が1バイト文字に限られているのであれば、string型の変数`s`に対して単に`s[i:j]`とすると部分文字列が得られます。
  - そうでない場合は、一旦[]rune型にキャストして操作すると良いです。たとえば`string([]rune(s)[i:j])`といった具合です。
- 今回の場合に限れば、最初の、[]byte型のハッシュ値の時点で部分列をとる方が簡単です。

Comment: 質問にも書かれていますが、`md5.Sum()` の戻り値の型が `[16]byte` なので `strMD5 := md5.Sum(...)[:15]` の様な書き方ができません。そのため、`tmp := md5.Sum(...);strMD5 := tmp[:15];` などとなってしまい、多少煩雑になってしまうかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

詳しい説明は[nekketsuuu さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/31634/3054)にあるので補足です。

> []byte型のハッシュ値の時点で部分列をとる

これをする場合、質問のように `[:30]` とやれば失敗しますので、16進表記の文字列に変換すると1バイトが2文字で表現されて要素数が倍になる事を考慮して`[:15]` とします。

ただ、今回は16進表記の文字列（全て ASCII の範囲内）に変換するので、変換後の `string` に対して文字数を使い、`[:30]` としても大丈夫です。

> 入力される文字列が1バイト文字に限られているのであれば、string型の変数sに対して単にs[i:j]とすると部分文字列が得られます。

とある通りです。

---

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ip := "192.0.2.0"
    sum := md5.Sum([]byte(ip))

    fmt.Printf("sum: %v\n", sum)
    fmt.Printf("len(sum): %d\n", len(sum))

    sumPart := sum[:15]

    fmt.Printf("sumPart: %v\n", sumPart)
    fmt.Printf("len(sumPart): %d\n", len(sumPart))

    sumPartFmt := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sumPart)

    fmt.Printf("sumPartFmt: %s\n", sumPartFmt)
    fmt.Printf("len(sumPartFmt): %d\n", len(sumPartFmt))

    sumPartHex := hex.EncodeToString(sumPart)

    fmt.Printf("sumPartHex: %s\n", sumPartHex)
    fmt.Printf("len(sumPartHex): %d\n", len(sumPartHex))
}
```

出力:

```
sum: [87 207 62 5 209 246 147 31 76 22 249 16 174 171 96 29]
len(sum): 16
sumPart: [87 207 62 5 209 246 147 31 76 22 249 16 174 171 96]
len(sumPart): 15
sumPartFmt: 57cf3e05d1f6931f4c16f910aeab60
len(sumPartFmt): 30
sumPartHex: 57cf3e05d1f6931f4c16f910aeab60
len(sumPartHex): 30
```

Comment: わかりやすい補足ありがとうございます